# Unit testing RxJava using Single.just(true) as the expected result

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, rx-java

```
Android Studio 3.0
RxJava-1
```

Unit testing the following code that will return a single with the result that could be either true or false depending if `findLastMessage` returns null or not.

```
 public Single<Boolean> hasLocalStorage() {
        return Single.fromCallable(() ->
                chatStorageHelper.findLatestMessage() != null);
    }
```

In my test case I have the following:
`storageHelper` is a mock that will return a non-null value for this case

```
@Test
    public void testHasLocalStorage_hasLocalStorage_returnTrue() {
        when(storageHelper.findLatestMessage()).thenReturn(new DBMessage());

        final Single<Boolean> result = Single.just(true);
        assertThat(localRepository.hasLocalStorage(), is(result));
    }
```

However, the test always fails because of this:

```
Expected :is <rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousSingle@712cfb63> 
Actual   :<rx.Single@32e54a9d>
```

When I check what `Single.just(true)` returns is the following:

```
public static <T> Single<T> just(final T value) {
        return ScalarSynchronousSingle.create(value);
    }
```

Calls the ScalarSynchronousSingle. I am wondering how can I change my test case so that a `rx.Single` is return from `Single.just(true)`?

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This lines will not work:

```
assertThat(localRepository.hasLocalStorage(), is(result));
```

because Single is a wrapper vor a Value, which may be produce in the Future. In fact you are assert if the reference of #hasLocalStorage return value is the same as the result.

You need to get the value from the hasLocalStorage-Single and from result, and compare its values.

For example you could use #toBlocking() and leave the reactive environment with #value().

```
  @Test
  void name2() throws Exception {
    final Object obj = new Object();

    Single<Object> just1 = Single.just(obj);
    Single<Object> just2 = Single.just(obj);

    Object value1 = just1.toBlocking().value();
    Object value2 = just2.toBlocking().value();

    assertThat(value1).isEqualTo(value2);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are trying to assert the references from two differents `Single`, one from your testing code and other from your production code. You will need to provide the `Single` from the constructor and, in your test, send it when you create that class.